# Posting Twitter and Facebook updates from a jQTouch / Phonegap iPhone app

Tags: javascript, iphone, jqtouch, cordova

I'm using jQTouch and Phonegap to write a simple iPhone app which i'm planning to release through the App Store.

Part of the planned functionality will let the user update their twitter or facebook status with the output of the App (some text, possibly a link).

Before I go ahead and start rolling my own solution, are there any JS libraries or plugins (or anything else) out there which will make this a lot simpler? Ive tried a few Google searches which havent turned up anything. The thought of all the authentication / error handling code is a bit daunting.

Thanks,

James.

Comment: do you have a working example connecting twitter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I endup implementing facebook and twitter login using the ChildBrowser plugin to authenticate as a mobile web site.

If this interesting for someone I could write a blog post about it.

http://github.com/purplecabbage/PhoneGap-Plugins/tree/master/ChildBrowser/

*Update:*
I just made the blog post: http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap

Hope it make sense, it explains how to login with facebook. I could make one about twitter login if someone is interested, but is basically the same.

Cheers, Sebastian

Comment: Thanks, it's a really good solution, and it can works on other platform too (like android, if childbrowser is implemented)

Comment: Is the python/django code runing on google app engine ? If yes, could be great to explain how to install it...

Comment: I managed to get the Facebook one working, struggling a fair bit with doing this in Twitter, I really could do with help here, I have managed to get up to the point of getting oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to todo the same thing, the only methods FB provides API's for is native code, or a mobile web site.  There is no in between (PhoneGap). I't appears its not possible besides writing a PhoneGap plugin for Twitter and Facebook (which is moderately difficult) or standing up a web site for your application and forwarding requests from there.

I myself decided to write a PhoneGap plugin using Facebook and Twitter's sample iPhone code.

Comment: would you like to share the PhoneGap plugin u made? @Josiah Hester

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the ChildBrowser with Phonegap/Android, but it didn't work due to API mismatches (the iPhone-version has event handlers for load finished etc, but the Android version doesn't).

But I used the Phonegap Facebook plugin to connect and it worked flawlessly.

I just refer to my earlier blog post which includes a step by step introduction how to connect to facebook inside a Phonegap environment:
http://blog.lagentz.com/phonegap/facebook-authentification-inside-phonegap-android/

Hope this helps,
Gregor